# Microsoft Visio 2007 crashing

Tags: crash, microsoft-visio-2007

Whenever I edit an existing project in Microsoft Visio it crashes. I have noticed it crashing specifically when I edit text.

Is this a known problem with a workaround?

**UPDATE:**
I am running Windows 7 with Office 2010, except for MS Project and MS Visio being 2007.

Comment: Does this happen with newly created projects or only this existing one?  I've had similar problems before and the only way to fix it was to copy and past what I was doing into a new file, either part by part or in one go.

Comment: From what I can tell it is only existing projects. Copying and pasting the project into a new file every time I need to edit doesn't seem like a viable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and discovered it is related to the Send to Bluetooth add-in

Launch Visio, go to Tools -> Trust Center.  Then select the Add-Ins option on the left.  At the bottom of the screen, press the Go button to Manage COM-Add Ins.  You should disable and remove the 'Send to Bluetooth' option.

Visio was crashing anytime I did anything: copy, edit text, open a file browser.  I am running Windows 7 64 bit with Visio 2007.  So far, this has resolved the crashes for me.

Source:
http://knightfoo.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/visio-2007-and-2010-crashing/

Comment: This also worked for me on Windows 7 x86 with Visio 2010